# Finding the smallest element in a Binary Search Tree - entering infinite loop

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am using recursive method to create a Binary Search Tree. My objective is to find the lowest element in the tree. Below is my code.

## Insertion

```
node insert(node root, int value)
{
        if ( root == NULL )
        {
                return ((newNode(value)));
        }

        if ( root->info == value )
        {
                std::cout<<"Duplicate entry found!"<<std::endl;
                return root;
        }
        else if ( root->info > value )
        {
                root->lChild = insert(root->lChild,value);
        }
        else if ( root->info < value )
        {
                root->rChild = insert(root->rChild,value);
        }
        else 
                std::cout<<"Some error has occurred.Time to debug!"<<std::endl;

        return root;
}
```

## MinValue Function

```
int minValue(node curPtr)
{
        node temp = curPtr;
        while ( curPtr )
        {
                temp = curPtr->lChild;
        }
        return (temp->info);
}
```

The reason why ( IMO ) my minValue() is entering into infinite loop is due to curPtr is always not NULL. How can i make it NULL after i have inserted the data using insert() function.

EDIT: Found the bug..so stupid of me. Thanks to Raymond

below is the edited minValue()

```
int  minValue(node curPtr)
{
  node temp = curPtr;
  while ( temp->lChild )
  {
     temp = temp->lChild;
  }
  return (temp->info);
}
```

Thanks
Kelly.

Comment: Note that since you pass `curPtr` by value in your `minValue` function, it is already copied: the `temp` variable is useless here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never modify curPtr in your loop.